# How do you fix 'IndexError: list index out of range' in Python

Tags: python

This is *supposed* to return a list of contestants from most to least based on the number of tasks they did (how many times they showed up in the input list), and if 2 contestants have the same number of tasks, then then sort those people by there times (least to greatest).

For example, when given this

```
["tyson 0:11", "usain 0:12", "carl 0:30", "carl 0:20", "usain 0:40", "carl 1:00", "usain 0:57"]
```

as input, it's supposed to return this:

```
["usain", "carl", "tyson"]
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to sort by time after sorting by tasks.

The code:

```
from  more_itertools import unique_everseen

def winners(data):
    names = []
    times = []
    taskcount = []
    ndict = {}

    for i in data:
        name = i.split()[0]
        time = i.split()[1]
        numMin, numSec = time.split(':')

        nmin = int(numMin)
        nsec = int(numSec)
        total = (60 * nmin) + nsec

        names.append(name)
        times.append(total)

    index = 0
    for name in names:
        count = names.count(name)
        taskcount.append(count)

    for name in names:
        taskcount.pop(0)

    taskcount = list(unique_everseen(taskcount))

    for name in names:    
        if name not in ndict:
            ndict[name] = [taskcount[index], times[index]]
        else:
            ndict[name][1] += times[index]
        index += 1
    sortedDict = sorted(ndict.items(),reverse = True , key=lambda kv: kv[1])
    R = [t[0] for t in sortedDict]
    return R
```

On top of that, it seems to work fine & dandy whenever I input a certain list but whenever I input others, it blows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-69-420jihgfedcc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Folder/contestWinner.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Folder')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Folder/contestWinner.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(winners(data))

  File "C:/Users/User/Folder/contestWinner.py", line 33, in winners
    ndict[name] = [taskcount[index], times[index]]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there anyway to fix the error & sort by time? Sorry if this is really stupid, I'm a beginner at Python.

Comment: After taskcount.pop(0) print taskcount and post the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer has dealt with the problem, but I'd like to suggest a more functional approach:

```
data = ["tyson 0:11", "usain 0:12", "carl 0:30", "carl 0:20", "usain 0:40", "carl 1:00", "usain 0:57"]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def process_time(t):
    minutes, seconds = map(int, t.split(':'))
    return 60 * minutes + seconds

def sort_key(pair):
    return (-len(pair[1]), min(pair[1]))

grouped = groupby(sorted(task.split() for task in data), 
                  key=itemgetter(0))

processed = {key: [process_time(time) for name, time in group] 
             for key, group in grouped}

print(processed)
print([name for name, time in sorted(processed.items(), key=sort_key)])
```

Output:

```
{'carl': [20, 30, 60], 'tyson': [11], 'usain': [12, 40, 57]}
['usain', 'carl', 'tyson']
```

First, we sort and group each entry in the input data by the first element, using `sorted` and `itertools.groupby`. This allows us to get our data in the more structured form of a `dict`, where the keys are names and the values are `lists` of times.

Along the way, we also process the strings representing times into an integer in seconds.

Next, we want to sort the `dict`'s keys by their values, first in decreasing order of length (because the length of the value is the number of tasks), then in increasing order of minimum time.

This is done by specifying a key function, `sort_key`, which, here, returns a `tuple`. The effect of the key function is that the input will be sorted *as if the key function was applied to it*.

`tuples` are sorted by their first element, then the second, and so on until all ties are broken or the last element is reached. In this case, we have a 2-tuple, where the first element is the *negative* length of the input and the second is the minimum value.

Note that the former is negative because `sorted`, by default, sorts in *ascending* order; by negating the length, we reverse the sort order. You can pass `reverse=True` in cases of sorting on only one element, but here we have two sorts in different orders.

The effect of all this is that we perform the required sort to get our answer.

Comment: This is a great answer, but the goal of the program is to find contestant with the smallest times with the largest amount of tasks completed. I'm really confused on how to do that, since sorted only sorts by one or the other (reverse or normally).

Comment: @PandaTobi Say you have a `list` of integers. Sorting them in ascending order is the same as sorting their negations in descending order. That's how my answer works.

Comment: I know that, but the problem I have is that the times have to be sorted in  order, on top of the tasks being sorted in  descending order. Sorry for the miscommunication!

Comment: @PandaTobi I'm sorry, I must not be getting something right. Aren't the times already sorted in ascending order in my answer?

Comment: Oh, I thought ascending was least to most. Sorry!

Comment: The point is that I can't figure out how to sort the 2 different measurements in 2 different orders. I Googled it but I'm not quite sure how to adapt that solution to your solution.

Comment: @PandaTobi Does my solution not work for your problem, or is my explanation on how it sorts *both* measurements in different orders not clear? Ascending *is* least to most, which is why `'usain'` is before `'carl'`, no?

Comment: Oooh!! I'm so sorry! I didn't realize that the sorted function sorted based on what was first and not what the combined values of the list was! Ughh. Is there anyway to combine the elements in the list?

Comment: @PandaTobi Combine in which way?

Comment: Like, add. The problem apparently requires the combined time of the contestant.

Comment: I tried using the sum() function to add all the elements of the value list, but that doesn't work. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because of these lines:

```
for name in names:
    taskcount.pop(0)

taskcount = list(unique_everseen(taskcount))
```

Removing these also removes the error.

However, your code still wont return the order you expect, because it is putting the greater time first. You will get `[('carl', [3, 110]), ('usain', [3, 109]), ('tyson', [1, 11])]` at the end, or when returned `['carl', 'usain', 'tyson']`, because carl has a longer total time then usain.

It should just be a matter of tweaking the line `sortedDict = sorted(ndict.items(),reverse = True , key=lambda kv: kv[1])` so it sorts by time in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
 from collections import Counter

data_release = ["tyson 0:11", "usain 0:12", "carl 0:30", "carl 0:20", "usain 0:40", "carl 1:00", "usain 0:57"]


def sorted_data(data):
    temp_data = []
    for item in data:
        item = item.split()[0]
        temp_data.append(item)

    temp_dict = dict(Counter(temp_data))
    sorted_list = sorted(temp_dict.items(), key=lambda d: - d[1])

    result = []
    for temp_tuple in sorted_list:
        result.append(temp_tuple[0])

    return result


    print(sorted_data(data_release))
```

Make full use of python collections lib,  The problem will be more simple!

Comment: Thank you lan! This is a really simple & Pythonic approach that I didn't even consider. However, this doesn't deal with the time based aspect of the problem. Is there a way to sort after the tasks in an ascending order for the times (ignoring the entries with lower amounts of tasks)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with a slight tweak of gmds's code, so I'm going to accept his/hers. I used a simple nested for loop that replaced each value of `processed` with the list of the combined times in the original value. Thanks gmds!

Code:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def winners(data):
    def process_time(t):
        minutes, seconds = map(int, t.split(':'))
        return 60 * minutes + seconds

    def sort_key(pair):
        return (-len(pair[1]), min(pair[1]))

    grouped = groupby(sorted(task.split() for task in data), key=itemgetter(0))

    processed = {key: [process_time(time) for name, time in group]
                 for key, group in grouped}

    for name in list(processed.keys()):
        length = len(processed.get(name))
        value = []
        for i in range(length):
            value.append(sum(processed.get(name)))

        processed[name] = value

    sortedL = [name for name, time in sorted(processed.items(), key = sort_key)]
    return sortedL

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = ["owen 2:00", "jeff 1:29", "owen 1:00", "jeff 1:30", "robert 0:21"]    
    print(winners(data))
```

Thanks for the help guys!